# ui:repeat in jsf 2.2 is working but rendered

Tags: repeat, jsf-2.2

i have jsf 2.2 application

and i render a li-list like this

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{handler.list}">
    <li><h:outputLink value="#{urlHandler.getUrl(item)}">#{item.title}</h:outputLink></li>
</ui:repeat>
```

but somehow it renders to

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <ui:repeat><li><a href="xxx">l1</a></li></ui:repeat>
    <ui:repeat><li><a href="xxx">123</a></li></ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

i'm using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

any ideas why?

EDIT namespaces:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
xmlns:fn="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions" 
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
```

Comment: Which XML namespace did you use for `ui`?

Comment: What if you use the original `http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets` XML namespace? (change the others to `java.sun.com` domain as well) So far, you're not the first one who encountered a strange problem with the new XML namespace.

Comment: ok with the old ns everything is ok, should i use the old ns in all html files?

Comment: I had the same problem with <ui:repeat> inside a <ui:composition>. The  <ui:repeat> tag has been rendered with the new namespace (http://xmlns.jcp.org/), so I switched back to "http://java.sun.com/" and everything was cool. 8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that is now fixed in the latest 2.2.2-SNAPSHOT

Comment: can i now use the new namespace everywhere? or are there known issues left with it?

Comment: I am developing my project using latest 2.2.2 snapshot and I would strongly advise you to wait. I am running into bugs constantly. I would suggest to wait until MyFaces is released so that at least you have an alternative if you get blocked ;)

Comment: ok i already rolled back to 2.1 because of missing primefaces support